# Issue with getting transitions to work on appear

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, transition, nuxtjs3

Here is a reproduction link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vats7o?file=pages%2Findex.vue

The problem is that I want to make a transition on appear. I can't get it to work so it uses my custom animation. It just appears (because of the appear flag) and ignores my defined functions. I tried to find a workaround but couldn't find one. I'm using Nuxt3 wit Vue3. Is this an Issue from Vue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ssr:false` in `nuxt.config.ts`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vats7o-3xvzhp?file=pages%2Findex.vue

Also, for custom transitions I'd recommend using a dynamic name attribute...

```html
<transition :name="myTransitionName" appear/>
```

And then using css to define the transitions, as in the demo above.